# Whenever I am submitting a form, it is passing null values in .NET Core 6

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-6.0

`.cshtml` code:

```
@model Tuple<CI_platform.Entities.ViewModels.SheetViewModel, List<CI_platform.Entities.ViewModels.SheetViewModel>, List<CI_platform.Entities.ViewModels.SheetViewModel>>
```

These are the view models I want in this `.cshtml`.

This is my form in `.cshtml`:

```
<form method="post" asp-action="sheetdatabase" asp-controller="TimeSheet">
    <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="d-flex flex-column">
            <label for="mission">Mission</label>
            <select id="mission" asp-for="@Model.Item1.MissionId">
                <option>Select Mission</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="d-flex flex-column mt-2">
            <label for="date">Date Volunteered</label>
            <input type="date" placeholder="select date" id="date" asp-for="@Model.Item1.DateVolunteered" />
        </div>
        <div class="d-flex mt-2 justify-content-between">
            <div class="d-flex flex-column">
                <label for="hour">Hours</label>
                <input type="number" id="hour" asp-for="@Model.Item1.hour" />
            </div>
            <div class="d-flex flex-column mt-2">
                <label for="minute">Minutes</label>
                <input type="number" id="minute" asp-for="@Model.Item1.minute" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="d-flex flex-column">
            <label for="message">Message</label>
            <textarea id="message" placeholder="Enter your message" asp-for="@Model.Item1.Notes"></textarea>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="sendmail">Submit</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

This is the action I am passing this value to:

```
public IActionResult sheetdatabase(SheetViewModel model)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        foreach (var error in ModelState.Values.SelectMany(v => v.Errors))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(error.ErrorMessage);
        }
    }

    var user_id = long.Parse(HttpContext.Session.GetString("userid"));
    _timesheetRepository.sheetdatabase(model, user_id);

    return View("volunteersheet");
}
```

Here whenever I am submitting the form, in the controller, the object is always null even though I am filling the values in input and other tags it is post method.

This is my get method for `volunteersheet.cshtml`:

```
public IActionResult volunteersheet()
{
    var (entity1,entity2) = _timesheetRepository.getdatasheet();
    var model1 = new SheetViewModel();
    var tuple = new Tuple<SheetViewModel, List<SheetViewModel>, List<SheetViewModel>>(model1, entity1, entity2);

    return View(tuple);
}
```

Here I am passing one instance two list these two list are for fetching data from database and show it to view:

```
public class SheetViewModel
{
    public long UserId { get; set; }
    public long MissionId { get; set; }
    public string missiontitle { get; set; }
    public long hour { get; set; } = new long();
    public long minute { get; set; } = new long();
    public TimeSpan Time { get; set; }

    public int Action { get; set; } = new int();

    public DateTime? DateVolunteered { get; set; }

    public string Notes { get; set; }
}
```

This is my model.

This code fetches the value form database correctly and also showing in view but whenever I am submitting the form the model in sheet database action is always null - please help me with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> @model Tuple<CI_platform.Entities.ViewModels.SheetViewModel, List<CI_platform.Entities.ViewModels.SheetViewModel>, List<CI_platform.Entities.ViewModels.SheetViewModel>>

This seems to be the source of the issue, `asp-for="@Model.Item1.{PropName}"` will post data with `Item1.{PropName}` while model binding expects just `{PropName}`. You need either mimic the structure of model in the receiving action or use customized binding. Try one of the following:

```cs
public IActionResult sheetdatabase([Bind(Prefix = "Item1")] SheetViewModel model)
```

Read more:

- [Model Binding in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding?view=aspnetcore-7.0)
- Also I hugely recommend following - [C# Coding Conventions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/coding-style/coding-conventions) (unless you have specific ones in your team)
- [Pass data to views](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/overview?view=aspnetcore-7.0#pass-data-to-views) - personally I would move away from using tuples to pass data to view, I would either use `ViewData` or combined the tuple elements into the model possibly excluding some stuff via [`BindNeverAttribute`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding?view=aspnetcore-7.0#bindnever-attribute)

Comment: Tuple<SheetViewModel> model it is giving me error that it cannot make instance of tuple

Comment: @GALAXYA50 then try other approaches.